# Nodeunit testing with Visual Studio 2015 Community (NTVS installed)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, nodeunit, ntvs

I would like to know if there is any tool that would allow me to test and run nodeunit tests in Visual Studio Community 2015 (with Node tools installed). I've heard of VsNodeTest but it's not compatible with Visual Studio 2015. Is there any tool or way for me to do this? Further, the tests are in typeScript. Thanks for the assistance, Luis